# Modify PHP config arrays from bash

Tags: php, arrays, bash, configuration, sed

I am writing my first BASH script to automate configuration of my (Laravel) web projects.

I have some config files (`app/config/local/database.php`,`app/config/app.php`) with PHP arrays that I need to access and modify. For example ...

```
'providers' => array(
    /** Append new service provider value, if it does not exist already */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    // ...
)
```

... or ...

```
'mysql' => array(
    /** Replace value under key "database" to "test_db" */
    'database' => 'homestead',
    'username' => 'homestead',
)
```

So far I was using `sed` expressions like this:

```
$LV_DB_NAME="test_db"
$LV_DB_FILE="app/config/local/database.php"
gsed -i "s/'database' .*/'database' => '$LV_DB_NAME',/g" $LV_FILE_DB_CONFIG
```

This feels a little messy to me, especially in the case of example 1.

### What would be awesome

Is there any way to get PHP arrays to BASH arrays and work with like you would in PHP?

**Example 1**

```
if (!in_array($new_provider, $providers)) {
    $providers[] = $new_provider;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
$config['mysql']['database'] = $database_name
```

### Update: What would also be awesome

If there is any other common way how to modify PHP arrays using terminal, I would be glad if you point me to it! I'm sure I'm not the only one who needs to modify PHP configuration arrays using terminal.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that, and also I'm wondering why use bash? Can't you make your script in PHP? Then you could be handling your arrays like... PHP arrays :-)

Comment: @mTorres: My bash script does a lot of "bash stuff" - utilising Composer, Vagrant commands, etc. It would be nice, if I could do all the grunt work linked with bootstraping a project from a single script.

Comment: If you think *that* sed expression is messy, you probably shouldn't use sed.

Comment: Well, That is the purpose of my question. I think `sed` is messy in this particular situation. Can you guide me to something *I should use?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mTorres was actually right. If your machine has `php cli` installed (which is probable), You can easily jump into PHP from your bash scripts. There are multiple ways to do so, I finally settled with this:

```
print_s "Putting data to file \"$PATH\" ... "
export PATH=$PATH
export DATA_JSON=$DATA_JSON

/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'

<?php

    $path = getenv("PATH");
    $data = getenv("DATA_JSON");

    $data = json_decode($data);
    $config = (file_exists($path) && is_array($config_data = require($path))) ? $config_data : array();

    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $config[$k] = $v;
    }

    file_put_contents($path, "<?php \n \n return ".var_export($config,true).";");

?>

EOF

}
```

There are some gotchas with passing associative arrays in BASH, check my other question: [Pass BASH associative arrays to PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381410/pass-bash-associative-arrays-to-php-script)