# Pass BASH associative arrays to PHP script

Tags: php, bash, eval, associative-array, getopt

Is it possible to pass BASH associative arrays as argv to PHP scripts?

I have a bash script, that collects some variables to a bash associative array like this. After that, I need to send it to PHP script:

```
typeset -A DATA
DATA[foo]=$(some_bash_function "param1" "param2")
DATA[bar]=$(some_other_bash_function)

php script.php --data ${DATA[@]}
```

From PHP script, i need to access the array in following manner:

```
<?php

    $vars = getopt("",array(
        "data:"
    ));

    $data = $vars['data'];

    foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
          echo "$k is $v";
    }

?>
```

### What I've tried

Weird syntax around the `--data` parameter follows advice from a [great post about bash arrays from Norbert Kéri](http://ihaveabackup.net/2012/01/02/arrays-in-bash/) how to force passed parameter as an array:

> You have no way of signaling to the function that you are passing an array. You get N positional parameters, with no information about the datatypes of each.

However this sollution still does not work for associative arrays - only values are passed to the function. Norbert Kéri made a [follow up article](http://ihaveabackup.net/2012/01/29/a-workaround-for-passing-arrays-in-bash/) about that, however its `eval` based solution does not work for me, as I need to pass the actual array as a parameter.

Is the thing I'm trying to achieve impossible or is there some way? Thank you!

### Update: What I am trying to accomplish

I have a few PHP configuration files of following structure:

```
<?php
return array(
    'option1' => 'foo',
    'option2' => 'bar'
)
```

My bash script collects data from user input (through bash `read` function) and stores them into bash associative array. This array should be later passed as an argument to PHP script.

```
php script.php --file "config/config.php" --data $BASH_ASSOC_ARRAY
```

So instead of complicated `sed`s functions etc. I can do simple:

```
<?php

    $bash_input = getopt('',array('file:,data:'));
    $data = $bash_input['data'];

    $config = require($config_file);
    $config['option1'] = $data['option1'];
    $config['option2'] = $data['option2'];

    // or

    foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
         $config[$k] = $v;
    }

    // print to config file
    file_put_contents($file, "<?php \n \n return ".var_export($config,true).";");
?>
```

This is used for configuring Laravel config files

Comment: Could you echo the bash array to a temporary file and then read that file? (as ugly as that would be)

Comment: Or you could pipe them into it and read the stdin?

Comment: I am a bash novice, so I need to figure out how to "echo" or "pipe" to file first and how exactly it will help my case. :) However if you would have time to elaborate to an answer ... And yes, I can work with creating files, as I `source` scripts from the main bash.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use bash array?

Comment: @ZanderRootman: I'm afraid so, as I am collection the data from user input (`read` function) in terminal ...

Comment: Have you looked into maybe serializing the user input to something like JSON or XML and then only sending over the serialized string? Then you don't have to worry about the PHP interpreter trying to figure out what you're trying to send it.

Comment: @ZanderRootman: Not yet, as I was hoping for a little lighter and portable solution, as I am running the PHP script after 2-3 questions to the user for, say, 5 times ...

Comment: The question is which is lighter then? De-serialization on PHP side, or manipulating data in bash to be readable by PHP interpreter (Which IS serialization). Would be nice to benchmark this, bash vs. php.

If you can't find any simple way to do this anything you do from this point on forward will have overhead.

Comment: @ZanderRootman: I will take a look into serialization than! Could you check the update to my question, where I am explaining what exactly I am trying to achieve? Thanks a bunch for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different Approach to @will's

**Your bash script:**

```
typeset -A DATA
foo=$(some_bash_function "param1" "param2")
bar=$(some_other_bash_function)

php script.php "{'data': '$foo', 'data2': '$bar'}"
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

    $vars = json_decode($argv[1]);

    $data = $vars['data'];

    foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
          echo "$k is $v";
    }

?>
```

**EDIT (better approach)** *Credit to @will*

```
typeset -A DATA
DATA[foo]=$(some_bash_function "param1" "param2")
DATA[bar]=$(some_other_bash_function)

php script.php echo -n "{"; for key in ${!DATA[@]}; do echo - "'$key'":"'${DATA[$key]}'", | sed 's/ /,/g' ; done; echo -n "}"
```

Comment: This is definately cleaner, but i think it would be much nicer if you made the json encoding automatic, something like `echo -n "{"; for key in ${!assoc_array[@]}; do echo -n "'$key'":"'${assoc_array[$key]}'",; done; echo -n "}"` ( i don't know if json minds the extra trailing comma at the end though, so you might need to trim that off...

Comment: Yeah the trailing comma would break the syntax. But a trim wont hurt anyone. Will update the answer quick

Comment: This is pretty much the thing I was trying to accomplish with Zander's code at the moment, yet more elegant. :) Thanks guys, you both helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

this does what you want (i think) all in one bash script. You can obviously move the php file out though.

```
declare -A assoc_array=([key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 [key3]=value3 [key4]=value4)

#These don't come out necesarily ordered
echo ${assoc_array[@]} #echos values
echo ${!assoc_array[@]} #echos keys

echo "" > tmp

for key in ${!assoc_array[@]}
do
echo $key:${assoc_array[$key]} >> tmp   # Use some delimeter here to split the keys from the values
done

cat > file.php << EOF
<?php

    \$fileArray = explode("\n", file_get_contents("tmp"));

    \$data = array();

    foreach(\$fileArray as \$line){
        \$entry = explode(":", \$line);
        \$data[\$entry[0]] = \$entry[1];
    }

    var_dump(\$data);

?>
EOF


php file.php
```

the escaping is necessary in the cat block annoyingly.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try right now and get back in a minute.

Comment: Will, your approach worked, although I will probably settle for (heavily modified) @ZanderRootman's approach. Thanks a lot, you taught me a lot about temporary bash data storage to files!